# Magento - page title on contact page

Tags: magento

how can i change the page title `<title>` of Magento's default contact page?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the title by overriding the "contacts.xml" layout file in your design. Adjust the following line to suit:

```
<action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<reference name="head">
     <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts">
          <title>Online Shopping, Shop Mobile online</title>
     </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open or find file like:
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/contacts.xml

Somewhere between contacts_index_index tags add:

```
    <reference name="head">

        <action method="setTitle"><title>Contact Us - Your Store Name</title></action>

    </reference>
```

Best,
Marek